# Integrate kedro debugger with docker container

Tags: docker, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, kedro

I'm currently trying to set up the debugger for kedro in VScode adding the following launch.json as the [documentation](https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/development/set_up_vscode.html?highlight=debug#debugging) suggests.

The thing is, I have 2 different docker containers that I would like to use to debug my kedro pipelines, so this lauch.json file does not work for me, because it executes the debugger in the normal terminal, not inside the docker terminal, so my question is, is there a way to do this and make it so that I can choose from which container debug it??

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Kedro Run",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "module": "kedro",
            "args": ["run"]
            // Any other arguments should be passed as a comma-seperated-list
            // e.g "args": ["run", "--pipeline", "pipeline_name"]
        }
    ]
}
```